# What could cause Realm to lock up when attempting a write?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm, reactive-programming

My team is currently facing an issue in our Xamarin.Forms app across all platforms(Android, iOS, and UWP). Realm will frequently become unresponsive, where the only way to use it again is to close the app. Over the past few months it's become more frequent and easy to reproduce, yet we have not been able to determine the cause or a workaround.

We have identified a few patterns that may help identify what's happening. We've noticed that whenever something that needs information from the database, we'll see that worker thread stuck on a `Realm.Write()` call. This behavior seems almost as if there's a deadlock occuring within the Realm system. It's not consistent as to which `Write()` call it's stuck on, seeming to be random based on when the Realm fails. At that point, any other attempts to access this realm through any method, such as `Find()`,`All()`,`Remove()`, etc also get stuck. We've also confirmed that the code within the `Write()` is never being run at this point, since we can put a realm independent logging call on the first line and never see it in our logs.

Once this issue occurs, some other issues can happen in addition to this. We have two other Realms in our app that handle completely separate data, and as such have no overlapping code. These Realms are never the cause of this issue, but when the problem Realm gets stuck, it sometimes causes the other Realms to get stuck on their next calls as well. This issue also sometimes persists between uses of the app, causing the very first call to Realm to get stuck and requires a complete reinstall to fix.

Due to our app using Reactive based programming, we've had to structure how we handle our database a bit differently. For the problem Realm, we have a service that keeps a single instance active in an observable stream, which can then be subscribed to for watching changes. I've added some examples of this architecture at the end of this post. We also route all our other non-observable actions through this stream, however during debugging we've been able to move these calls to their own independent realm instances with little issue/no change to functionality.

Currently, we're thinking it's most likely an issue related either to how we're converting Realm to an observable system, or with our Realms crashing/becoming corrupted somehow.

RealmStream declaration:

```
_realmStream = Observable
    .Start(() => Realm.GetInstance(_dbConfig), _scheduler)
    .Do(_ => logger.LogTrace("Realm created"), () => logger.LogTrace("Realm stream completed"))
    .Replay()
    .AutoConnect();
```

RealmStream use example:

```
public IObservable<IChangeSet<TResult>> GetChangeSetStream<TSource, TResult>(Func<Realm, IQueryable<TSource>> selector, Func<TSource, TResult> transformFactory) where TSource : RealmObject
{           
    return _realmStream
        .Select(realm =>
            selector(realm)
                .AsRealmCollection()
                .ToObservableChangeSet<IRealmCollection<TSource>, TSource>()
                .SubscribeOn(_scheduler)
                .Transform(transformFactory)
                .DisposeMany())
        .Switch()
        .Catch<IChangeSet<TResult>, Exception>(ex =>
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error getting property change stream");
            return Observable.Return<IChangeSet<TResult>>(default);
        })
        .SubscribeOn(_scheduler);
}
```

Non-Observable realm methodss:

```
public async Task Run(Action<Realm> action)
{
    await _realmStream
        .Do(action)
        .SubscribeOn(_scheduler);
}

public async Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Realm, TResult> action)
{
    return await _realmStream
        .Select(action)
        .SubscribeOn(_scheduler);
}
```

So far, we've attempted the following:

- Made sure Realm and Xamarin are both on the most recent versions
- Reducing the number of `Realm.Write()`s (Minor improvement)
- Moving every Realm function into our observable system (No noticable change, most of our functions already do this)
- Attempted moving everything that does not require observables to using independent realm instances (increased frequency of locking)
- Attempted to move everything away from our single instance of Realm. We weren't able to do this, as we could not determine how to properly handle some observable events, such as a RealmObject being deleted, without causing major performance issues

Answer (score 0):

`realm.Write` needs to acquire a write lock and based on your description, it appears that you do get a deadlock where a thread with an open write transaction waits for another thread that is stuck on the `realm.Write` call. If you're able to reproduce the hand with a debugger attached, you can inspect the threads window and try to pinpoint the offending code.

[This article](https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-deadlocks-in-depth-part-1/) provides some tips about debugging deadlocks. Unfortunately, without the whole project and a repro case, it'd be hard to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: So could the issue potentially be an action passed into the write is faulty, and is failing inside a realm write to prevent it from releasing it's internal lock? If that's the case, is there a way to see which thread/function is currently holding the lock? I've used the threads window to see which write call is unable to access the lock, but there's no info on which thread is holding it.

Comment: A write being faulty is a bit ambiguous - if it throws an exception, that will be handled and the transaction will be rolled back, thus releasing the lock. A more likely scenario is an action within a realm.Write calling into something on a different thread that also tries to do a realm.Write. In the threads window, you can see what statement each thread has paused on - if my theory is correct, one should be paused on a realm.Write, and another - on something within a realm.Write.

Comment: After a few days of working on this, we don't think this is an issue with nested realm writes. My team has gone through every write in our code, and while we did find a remove a small number of them, we are still encountering this issue. We also still don't see any other threads in our threads window related to realm writes. Is this something that could potentially be caused by threading work within the write, even without a nested write? We have several writes in our app that use things such as async-await or observables, could that potentially cause issues?

Comment: You should probably not be using `await` within a transaction if that's what you mean. If you mean that you're using async-await before opening or after committing a transaction, that should be fine, as long as you're taking care to ensure a Realm is not used across threads. If you can isolate a small project that reproduces the issue or are willing to share your code, feel free to open a Github issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues - SO is more geared towards answers than discussions.